# Difference between manually rebooting an android device and using android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED?

Tags: android, android-intent, reboot, bootcompleted

I need to develop one action once the android device starts.

To test it, I know that instead of manually rebooting the device, it is possible to use adb like the following code:

```
adb shell
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

to simulate the rebooting. Nevertheless, I noticed the behavior is different in the two cases.

What is the difference between android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and manually rebooting the device? Is there another intent to use instead of BOOT_COMPLETED? (in my particular case I am testing with a device with Android 6.0.1)

Thanks everyone

Comment: Please explain in detail what differences in behavior you are observing .

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know exactly. Basically I start OpenVPN and I should send username and password. Using the simulation with the intent it works fine, instead manually rebooting the device, OpenVPN starts but it is blocked waiting the credentials. Since this part of the code is not done by me, I do not know more details at the moment. (The application starts using intents and the credentials using the aidl interface)

Comment: Presumably, sending a fake BOOT_COMPLETED will allow you to check that your code responds to the signal, and that it at least _tries_ to do what it needs to do in response to a reboot. However, because the machine won't have _just_ been rebooted, if those actions depend on the state of the machine immediately after rebooting, it won't be a full test.

Comment: Mmm ehat you say sounds reasonable, even if since all the applications are closed and the initial logo appears, i expected a complete refresh of the device. Do you have some link to the official documentation? I could not find it. I am curious of knowing what the test action really does.

Comment: I suspect it's a difference between "boot completed" and "device ready and raring to go". I don't know exactly when BOOT_COMPLETED is sent, but I would imagine it's pretty soon after the "core OS" is up and running, but _before_ things like 3G/4G/Wifi are up and running or third-party apps are started (they, presumably, would start on receiving the signal). By contrast, when a "test" version is sent, the device _is_ fully up and running. My guess is that your response to the (real) message must check-for and wait-for, things like a network connection and other dependencies to be established.